# How to make login using either Username or email id

Tags: cakephp

I am developing a website in cakephp.
I want to give facility to login either using username or emailid.

I am using.
 $this->Auth->fields['email'] ='username';

when the login failed and try to relogin again.
But till now i haven't got success.

Can anybody suggest me any other idea to that or what i m missing.
I have desabled the autorediret also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can set up `AuthComponent` in the `beforeFilter` callback, I would assume that you should also be able to do some switching there:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if (
        isset($this->data['User']['login']) && // login form has been posted
        Validation::email($this->data['User']['login']) // value looks like an email
    ) {
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email'); // change the db field
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to try an earlier filter, such as `beforeRender`, since you need to fire your code before [`AuthComponent::startup()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentstartup). As a last resort, you can [extend the AuthComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141415/how-can-i-use-cookies-for-authentication-in-cakephp/1143090#1143090):

```
App::import('Component', 'AuthComponent');
class AppAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {

    function startup() {
        # your code here
        parent::startup();
    }
}
```